# How to delete files or an image in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, delete-file

How to delete files in laravel 5.4
I tried this

```
\Storage::delete($path);
```

and this

```
\File::delete($path);
```

and it told me Method delete does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think your Files and Images are in Folder and Database. So , you need to Delete Files and Images from Folder and Database. I think you have already created a Delete button in View file and you have passed the id. Then try this..

> after `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` , write this below codes.

```
use DB;

use File;
```

> In your Controller file code like this.

I think your Files and Images store in public folder. That why I use \File::

```
function delete($id)
    {
        $query = DB::table('academic')->where('id',$id);

        $files_to_delete = $query->pluck('Db_ImageorFile_Column_Name')->toArray(); //keeping the result in a php

        $query->delete(); // For delete from database
        \File::delete($files_to_delete); // For delete from folder  

        return redirect('Your_Page_Name');
    }
```

If you have further Questions , use these Links -

1. ) [How To Delete Files Or Images From Folder And Database In Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551170/how-to-delete-files-or-images-from-folder-and-database-in-laravel)
2. ) [How to delete file from public folder in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1)
3. ) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-delete-a-file-or-a-photo-from-the-folder-when-deleting-it-from-database?page=1