# How To Delete Files Or Images From Folder And Database In Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a Registration form. And I have created a Table to show all the data which is in Database. And there is a button called Delete and I have passed the unique id. When I click that Delete button , it deletes the data from Database. But , I want to Delete Files or Images from Database and Folder. 
My Files and Images stored in the public folder.

How can I Fix this ??

> Delete button code. ( RegView.blade.php )

```
@foreach($data as $value )
<tr>
<td> <a href="delete{{ $value->id }}"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn-danger"></a> </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

> Code for controller. ( RegViewController.blade.php )

```
 function delete($id)
    {
        DB::table('academic')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect('RegView');
    }
```

> Here is the Routes that I have created.

```
Route::get('delete{id}','RegViewController@delete');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#deleting-files

Comment: @aynber - Thank U Very Much Bro !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a solution, i.e: setup the query builder to find the file:

```
$query = DB::table('academic')->where('id',$id);
```

Assuming the file_path is a field that keeps the path in your table

```
$files_to_delete = $query->pluck('file_path')->toArray(); //keeping the result in a php 
$query->delete(); //now deleting
Storage::delete($files_to_delete);
```

> PS: You can read more about similar methods with Storage in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#deleting-files) and only one important info in the doc is the following:

[image]

Meaning that it looks for 'storage/app' directory to find that file.

Comment: @KistlakRajapaksha file_path is just an example of the field that has the file name. Can you show the fields you have in your academic table, in the question?

Comment: My Files and Images stored in the public folder. So , How can I Fix it ?

Comment: if they are files that should is not generally used in the view, they can be in storage. I think that better, however if they are in public (and should be there) then you can use `File::delete($files);` ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Still , it didn't delete from the Folder.. why is that ??

Comment: Add a \ before File. i.e `\File::delete()` By the way, see it seems you have an answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-delete-a-file-or-a-photo-from-the-folder-when-deleting-it-from-database?page=1

Comment: Now it's Working 100% Perfectly !! I tried all of these articles , but didn't work for me.. That why I have posted here.. Thank U Very Much Bro !! :D

Comment: glad it worked. I'll add the delete method to the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pathToYourFile = 'example/someimage.jpeg';// get file path from table
if(file_exists($pathToYourFile)) // make sure it exits inside the folder
{
  unlink($pathToYourFile); // delete file/image
  // and delete the record from database
}
```

Comment: Still , it Deletes from Database. But , didn't delete from the Folder.. How can I Fix this ??