# unlink(\public\images/backend_images/category_images/): Permission denied

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to delete images from DB, but it shows below error:

```
unlink(\public\images/backend_images/category_images/): Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me where is a mistake in my code?

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    $image = $category->image;

    $image = public_path("images/backend_images/category_images/$image");
    if (file_exists($image)) unlink($image);


    $category->delete();

    return redirect(route('admin.category.index'))->with('flash_message_error', 'Category has been Deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: Did you try `chmod -R 775 /images` ?

Comment: m using windows

Comment: where did you place your public folder, windows don't usually ask for permission!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete file from public folder in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @KulshreshthK public/images/backend_images/category_images/