# how to delete multiple records that involve images in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Please guys any idea how to delete multiple records that involve images. i do not know any approach that i can use. i have tried a lot.this is the what i have tried  below.Pls help me guys i really need your help.Thanks in advance

please this is the code below

```
public function multipleUserDelete(Request $request,$id, $post_image){

    if ($request->isMethod("post")) {
        $data=$request->all();   

        //$del_user = $request->del_user;
        // $ids=$del_user[];
        //foreach(session('posts') as $session){


        //foreach(session('products') as $postDelete){

        $postDeletes=Post::where(['id'=> $id])
                            ->where('post_image', $post_image)
                            ->get();

        foreach ($postDeletes as $postDelete) {
            # code...

            // $postDeletes=Post::where(['id'=> $id])->get();
    //}
            $large_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/small/';

            $medium_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/medium/';

            $small_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/large/';

            //Delete Image permenently from product table begins 

            //Delete Large image if not exist

            if(file_exists($large_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image)){
                unlink($large_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image);    
            }

            //Delete Large image if not exist            
            if(file_exists($small_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image)){
                unlink($small_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image);    
            }

            //Delete Medium image if not exist
            if(file_exists($medium_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image)){
                unlink($medium_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image);    
            }
        }


        //$del_id=$request->input('del_feedback');

        Post::whereIn('id', $data['del_user'])->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with("flash_message_success","you Successfully Deleted The Selected Users(s)");
    }
```

Comment: Your stored file is in `public` folder or `storage` folder .

Comment: i stored the file in the public folder

Comment: Please check the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think something like this should work fine.

```
$image_path = "/images/";  // Value is not URL but directory file path
Post::where(['id'=> $id])
        ->where(function($query){

             if(File::exists($image_path . $post_image)) {
                 File::delete($image_path . $post_image);
             }
              $query->where('post_image', $post_image)
          })
         ->delete();
```

Comment: too few argument to function that is the error it brings now

Comment: @Mutairu  can you edit your question and show me exactly what you tried using my code?

Comment: multiple delete that involve images and texts from database.the images must be permanently delete from public folder .in the  frontend i will use checkbox to select those that i want to delete from the table and click on delete button

Comment: @Mutairu  File::delete() is similar to unlink only, but in laravel style implementation, you need to paas path to delete the file, and for whichever record you will match, you want to delete the records too, as per my understanding, so pass path delete files and records, using where closure, check documentation for correct syntax, but this should be done in a simplest and sort way.

Comment: thanks for the concern this is the error i am getting now:Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::multipleUserDelete(), 1 passed and exactly 3 expected

Comment: @Mutairu in you controller `multipleUserDelete` function definition has 3 arguments, check your request route and request parameter, if you are sending  3 or not, it is not related to inside logic, that I have posted.

Comment: what i mean is that may be your code needs a a little bit of manipulation in order to work.i really appreciate your gesture bro.thanks a  lot

Comment: @Mutairu Actually, if you know tinker, you can test it with 1/2 records, to know what modification you may need.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the path issue should probably be 
absolute.

See [How to delete file from public folder in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1)
I don't know in Laravel 6, but it should work.

i.e. using File :: delete ()

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder that contains your image to your config/filesystems.php files:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path('app'),
    ],
    //Above bit should already be there. So add this....  

    'some-image-path' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path("wherever/your/directory/is/from/root/"),
    ],
```

You would then use it like this:

```
  $myImage = 'some-image.png'; 
  Storage::disk('some-image-path')->delete($myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function multipleUserDelete(Request $request,$id, $post_image){

    if ($request->isMethod("post")) {
        $data=$request->all();   

        $postDeletes=Post::where(['id'=> $id])
                            ->where('post_image', $post_image)
                            ->get();
        $img_array = array();
        foreach ($postDeletes as $postDelete) {
            $large_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/small/';

            $medium_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/medium/';

            $small_image_paths='images/backend_image/admin_users/large/';
            $img='';
            if(file_exists(public_path($large_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image))){
                $img = $large_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image;
            }

            if(file_exists(public_path($small_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image))){
                $img = $small_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image;
            }

            if(file_exists(public_path($medium_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image))){
                $img = $medium_image_paths. $postDelete->post_image;
            }

            array_push($img_array,$img);
        }

        \File::delete($img_array);
        Post::whereIn('id', $data['del_user'])->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with("flash_message_success","you Successfully Deleted The Selected Users(s)");
    }
```