# LARAVEL How to delete image from public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, sql-delete, delete-file

I am coding a blog post, when i click add post the image from any folder is put into **public/user/img/** 
How I delete it when i delete the whole table line? (click delete a post), please see the public function deletePost($id) below, I can delete the details (text) in a row but cannot delete the file in the folder.
Please help

```
public function deletePost($id){
    $posts = Post::where('id',$id);
    $posts->delete();
    return back()->with('delete_posts_success','Deleted!');
}

public function getAddPost() {
    return view('admin.publish');
}

public function postAddPost(Request $request) {
    $post = $request->all();


    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->author = $request->author;
    $post->content = $request->content;
    $post->intro = $request->intro;
    $post->type = $request->type;

    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if($extension != 'jpg' && $extension != 'png' && $extension != 'jpeg') {
            return back()->with('Error', 'File extension must be jpg, png, jpeg');
        }
        $imageName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move("user/img", $imageName);
        $post->image = $imageName;
    } else {
        $imageName = null; 
    }


    $post->save();
    return back()->with('create_posts_success','Published!');
}
```

Comment: First check file exits or not by fetching filename using deleted id if exits then unlink this file after delete query. `file_exists()`, `unlink()`

Comment: This will solved your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#deleting-files

Comment: please add explanation for why the question|answer is down-voted

Answer (score 0):

you must be saving filename in database somewhere for this uploaded post

now when you delete that post, 
-> get the name of the file from your db record,
-> check if the file exists at the location using `file_exists()`
-> delete the found file using `unlink()`

-> get file deletion response (true|false)

in your case, it becomes something like below

```
$filePathName = 'user/img/' . $post->image;
if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
   unlink($filePathName);
}
```

ignore my syntax mistakes please
Done