# Laravel unlink method

Tags: laravel

can someone tell me how to unlink image from public path when product is deleted.

My current code which does not work:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $image_path = '/uploads/products/' . $product->image;
        
        if(file_exists($image_path)){
            unlink($image_path);
        }

        $product->delete();
    }
```

Also tried:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);

        if(file_exists($product->image)){
            unlink($product->image);
        }

        $product->delete();
```

Also I am using accessor so my $product->image is returning:

```
"http://myeshop.local/uploads/products/1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg"
```

Here is accessor code:

```
public function getImageAttribute($image){
    return asset($image);
}
```

Comment: i think you should just checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842735/how-to-delete-file-from-public-folder-in-laravel-5-1#:~:text=14%20Answers&text=You%20could%20use%20PHP's%20unlink,%3A%3Adelete()%20method%20instead.

Comment: `unlink()` must delete the specified file. But you're not providing ABSOLUTE path for the file. So you've to provide an absolute path for the file you're going to delete.

Comment: No, it should but definitely must not. Ownership, perms etc

Comment: Oh! SeadSilajdzic MarcinOrlowski is definitely right in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

**use model deleted event**

```
//Product Model

protected static function boot()
{
     parent::boot();
    
     static::deleted(function($product){
        // getOriginal skip accessor
        $image = public_path('uploads/products/' . $product->getOriginal('image'));
        if(file_exists($image)) {
             unlink($image);
        }
    
     });
}
```

Comment: does this "getOriginal" gets only image path ? without website url.
Instead of: "http://myeshop.local/uploads/products/1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg"


I get "/uploads/products/1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg"
?

Comment: @SeadSilajdzic `getOriginal` gets the attribute before the accessor changes it

Answer (score 0):

`unlink($path)` is a PHP function. It will delete a file located at a local path. According to your question the value of $product->image is the complete URL to the image. If it is then the following is true:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$image_path = '/uploads/products/' . $product->image;

// $image_path = '/uploads/products/http://myeshop.local/uploads/products/1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg'
// and it needs to point to '/PATH/TO/LARAVEL/uploads/products/1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg'
// the following file_exists() will return false

if(file_exists($image_path)){
   unlink($image_path); // so you never get here
}
```

There are some quick and dirty ways to fix this, but the best thing to do is to have the `$product->image` property point to just the name of the file. Then in your view apply the file name to the `/uploads/products/` directory on the web server.

Doing this will allow you to apply the `/uploads/products/` local path and have a better time finding the file you want to delete. I'm assuming the uploads directory is in your Laravel `public` directory so you'd want to do something like this:

```
// $product->image must point to the filename only: 1593902362bluesocksupd.jpg
// The file_exists should evaluate to true and unlink() will work.

$image_path = public_path('uploads/products/' . $product->image);

if(file_exists($image_path)){
   unlink($image_path);
}
```

In your Blade template view you'd need to show the product image using something like this:

```
<img src="{{ url('/uploads/products/' . $product->image) }}" />
```

Storing a complete URL in your database doesn't scale well if you wanted to develop another website or reuse this code on another project. This way you can let Laravel manage where the URL or local file system is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's `unlink()` method. 
But if you want to do it the **Laravel** way, use the `Storage::delete` method instead :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $image_path =   public_path('uploads/products/' . $product->image);
        
        if(file_exists($image_path)){
            Storage::delete($image_path);
        }

        $product->delete();
    }
```